# Troubleshooting a crash with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, metadata

I have a folder with several thousand videos (All .MPG extensions).  When I open the folder with these videos, it shows up fine, but as I start scrolling down, it crashes the Windows Explorer.

In the Event Viewer, I see this:

```
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 6.1.7600.16450, time stamp: 0x4aebab8d
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16559, time stamp: 0x4ba9b802
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000c6df2
Faulting process id: 0x954
Faulting application start time: 0x01cbb1b71edf3b51
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: ee987372-1dc4-11e0-8e06-406186ea9135
```

I suspect that one of the videos has bad metadata.  I removed the Length column and it was still crashing.  I then removed the Date column and the problem disappeared.

How do I go about troubleshooting this problem or at least identifying the file that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be laborious, but have you tried moving these files onto an external hard drive and then moving each one individually. Otherwise, you could also try to run a virus scan on that folder and seeing if that helps as well.

Comment: Rather than one by one, do a binary search:  move half of them, the problem will either be there or not.  If the problem is there, remove half of the half.  Even with thousands, you can quicky find a single bad one using a binary search.

Comment: @Know - binary sounds like the solution, cause, I have thousands.