# Unknown explorer.exe crashes

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, crash, dump

Over the past week I have started to have explorer.exe crashes and as of yet have been unable to determine the cause. I am seeing in the event logs that explorer.exe is crashing and the faulting module is ntdll.dll. I really want to track down why this is happening and fix it rather than having to reinstall windows. This installation is only a month or so old. I would like to see if anyone has Ideas? Below is the event log report and the crash dump when viewed from windbg. Any feedback is welcome.

Event log data:

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17284, time stamp: 0x53f816dc
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17278, time stamp: 0x53eebd22
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f0d6c
Faulting process id: 0x1438
Faulting application start time: 0x01d01bb4f08e7948
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 84603404-87b2-11e4-825c-f8b156bf91ae
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Crash dump viewed in WinDBG:

```
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(1438.1254): Unknown exception - code c0000374 (first/second chance not available)
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa:
00007ffb`b0ff1c2a c3              ret
0:081> .ecxr
rax=000000000587e0b8 rbx=00000000c0000374 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=00007ffbb1089c60
rip=00007ffbb1050d6c rsp=000000000587e550 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000003  r9=00007ffb92659138 r10=00007ffbb0fb2653
r11=000000000000000c r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000003 r15=0000000000000002
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x8c:
00007ffb`b1050d6c eb00            jmp     ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x8e (00007ffb`b1050d6e)
```

Comment: Do you have Classic Shell installed? It's a program that puts the start menu back and restores some other Windows-8 changes. I have it on a couple of Windows-8.1 machines, and have occasionally seen really ugly interactions between it and Explorer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting a crash with Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/231952/troubleshooting-a-crash-with-windows-7)

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/619615/explorer-dies-silently-and-in-unexpected-ways

Comment: @Techie007 I researched this issue prior to posting. The zany amount of mpeg files doesn't seem to be related and the second one you linked doesn't garner any information that could be considered useful. Thanks for pointing out those threads though.

Comment: @Matthew I don't have that installed and as part of troubleshooting, I have upgraded all of my drivers, disabled all non-microsoft shell extensions, done a memory check, and sfc /scannow among other things. I think you are on the right path though it is my suspicion that it might not be a windows issue but 3rd party.

Comment: http://www.dlltool.com/help/fix-dll/extension-dll/ntdll/

Comment: @Slyce: Could you put a brief summary of what you tried in the question? It sounds like you've done a lot of troubleshooting yourself, which is great. If you post what hasn't worked, it will help those on the site narrow down the problem.

Comment: create a dump with AppVerifier enabled: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ and analyze this better dump in Windbg. If you're unsure, zip and share the dmp.